# Grails Hibernate: disable optimistic locking in super class

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have domain classes like Class A inherits Class B and C. I don't want any optimistic locking at Class A level but I want optimistic locking at class B level and not at class C level and in tables tableperhierarchy is true. 
I had tried to add

> version (false)

in class A mappings closure and

> version (true)

in class B mappings. But it always giving me version field as null even for class B objects as well. Anyone else too faced such issue?
I am working on grails 2.1.0 and groovy 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

This seems not to be possible in Hibernate. There is a way to specify [NONE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/OptimisticLockType.html#NONE) as optimistic lock type, [but in a hierarchy, it can be done only on the root entity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/OptimisticLocking.html).

You could extend class `A` by another abstract class `VersionedA`. Then all versioned entity classes can derive from `VersionedA`, and non-version ones can still extend `A` directly.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!! But the issue is there is no effect of version true inside mappings closure of subclass..